# android - NullPointerException for GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

in my case app always crash on Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline and i write below codes, but when running show me Force Close error

**ActivityMain**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    //Google Maps
    public GoogleMap mMap;

    //
    SQLHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //DB
        dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch (Exception ioe) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        //BUAT MAP
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.peta);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



        int simpul_awal = 0;
        int simpul_tujuan = 3;

        //output algoritma
        dijkstra algo = new dijkstra();
        algo.jalurTerpendek(this, simpul_awal, simpul_tujuan);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Jalur terdekat : "+algo.jalur_terpendek1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String[] exp = algo.jalur_terpendek1.split("->");

        int start = 0;
        //Query DB; Gambar Jalurnya!

        dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        for(int i = 0; i < exp.length-1; i++){
            ArrayList<LatLng> lat_lng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT jalur FROM graph where simpul_awal ="+exp[start]+" and simpul_tujuan ="+exp[(++start)], null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx_koord = 0;
            String[] exp_koord = cursor.getString(0).split(",");
            for(int j = 0; j < exp_koord.length/2; j++){
                lat_lng.add( new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(exp_koord[idx_koord]), Double.parseDouble(exp_koord[++idx_koord])) );
                ++idx_koord;
            }
            PolylineOptions jalurBiasa = new PolylineOptions();
            jalurBiasa.addAll(lat_lng).width(5).color(0xff4b9efa).geodesic(true);
            **mMap**.addPolyline(jalurBiasa);

        }

        //zoom ke koordinat
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT jalur FROM graph where simpul_awal ="+exp[0]+" and simpul_tujuan ="+exp[1], null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String[] koord = cursor.getString(0).split(",");
        **mMap**.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(koord[0]), Double.parseDouble(koord[1])), 12));



    }//oncreate

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kokoro1.com.kokoro1">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="kokoro1.com.kokoro1.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAIbPBUmnZ1TF0rHkGjLN-g1GNYHsnR5Uo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyLogcat**

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: kokoro1.com.kokoro1, PID: 26867
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kokoro1.com.kokoro1/kokoro1.com.kokoro1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)' on a null object reference
                      at kokoro1.com.kokoro1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use "mMap" variable after onMapReady is called :)

Comment: This is correct.  You are trying to use your GoogleMap object before it has been initialized.  There is no guarantee that when your code runs in the onCreate(), that your map is ready to work with.  Try moving your code to a method that you call after `mMap = googleMap;` in your onMapReady() callback.

Answer (score 0):

if(googleMap!=null)

these lines add before rising your error /code lines